# Error: Can see organization contacts but not individual contacts

Tags: contacts

On CiviCRM 5.48.2 on Drupal 7.89 I can view & edit any Organization contacts but not the individual ones and I get a `DB Error: syntax error`.

Logs record `"SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE parent_group_id IN () [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1]"`

What could cause this?

EDIT1:

```
[debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(941): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...")
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...")
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1928): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...", "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1234): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...")
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...")
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...")
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(468): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...")
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupNesting.php(201): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT child_group_id, parent_group_id FROM civicrm_group_nesting WHERE paren...")
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(671): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupNesting::getDescendentGroupIds((Array:1))
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Service/Spec/Provider/ContactGetSpecProvider.php(75): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::populateTemporaryTableWithContactsInGroups((Array:1), "civicrm_tmp_e_dflt_5eefab383b4b2d906e44d6983e2c6c7c")
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php(554): Civi\Api4\Service\Spec\Provider\ContactGetSpecProvider::getContactGroupSql((Array:32), "`a`.`id`", "IN", (Array:1), Object(Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery), 0)
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php(530): Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->createSQLClause("`a`.`id`", "IN", (Array:1), (Array:32), 0)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php(425): Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->composeClause((Array:4), "WHERE", 0)
#18 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php(298): Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->treeWalkClauses((Array:4), "WHERE")
#19 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php(150): Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->buildWhereClause()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php(165): Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->getSql()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/DAOGetAction.php(113): Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->run()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/DAOGetAction.php(101): Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction->getObjects(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(69): Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction->_run(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))
#24 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(149): Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction))
#25 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(234): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction))
#26 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.contactlayout/CRM/Contactlayout/BAO/ContactLayout.php(68): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.contactlayout/CRM/Contactlayout/BAO/ContactLayout.php(39): CRM_Contactlayout_BAO_ContactLayout::userIsIn(44, (Array:1))
#28 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.contactlayout/contactlayout.php(144): CRM_Contactlayout_BAO_ContactLayout::getLayout(1018)
#29 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(271): contactlayout_civicrm_pageRun(Object(CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary))
#30 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/DrupalBase.php(73): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:193), "civicrm_pageRun", 1, Object(CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#31 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(237): CRM_Utils_Hook_DrupalBase->invokeViaUF(1, Object(CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_pageRun")
#32 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(214): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), "hook_civicrm_pageRun", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#33 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:1), "hook_civicrm_pageRun", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(198): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_pageRun", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#35 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(167): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_pageRun", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#36 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(916): CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke((Array:1), Object(CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_pageRun")
#37 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php(205): CRM_Utils_Hook::pageRun(Object(CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary))
#38 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(86): CRM_Core_Page->run()
#39 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(319): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->run((Array:3), NULL)
#40 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#41 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#42 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(471): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#43 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("contact", "view")
#44 /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#45 {main}
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with the groups, can you add the backtrace to your message?

Comment: I've edited my post